# How do I get intellisense for record properties?

Tags: c#, .net, record

Given this code:

```
/// <summary>
/// When identity verification has occurred.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="ConsumerId">The id of the consumer</param>
public record IdentityVerificationDecidedEvent(String ConsumerId)
{       
}
```

I thought adding param name would do it, but it only does it on the ctor of the record object.  How do I decorate the

```
String ConsumerId
```

to get the intellisense comment for

```
myEvent.ConsumerId
```

to appear?

Comment: I do have intellisense comment when accessing property, though not sure if that's Resharper or not.